# Way to call upon a certain line itself of code?

Tags: java

I know that you can call a method, but is there a way to call a certain line of code itself?

```
System.out.println("If You Would like to restart the program, type \"Start\"");
    System.out.print(">");
    String restart= UserInput.next();

    if (restart.equals("Start")){
    }
```

For instance, how would, if the IF statement evaluates to true, get back to the top of the code (line 1) without going into a method? So how to call a line...

Comment: Don't do that. We're way passed labels and gotos in Java.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a [do-while loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html):

```
do {
    System.out.println("If You Would like to restart the program, type \"Start\"");
    System.out.print(">");
    String restart= UserInput.next();
} while (restart.equals("Start"));
```

Java actually *does* have a `goto` keyword, but it doesn't do anything. It was reserved in case some functionality will be assigned to it in the future. In any case, `goto` is generally universally discouraged anyway, and a loop approach should be preferred.

As an aside, please follow Java's naming conventions: `userInput` instead of `UserInput`.

Comment: Downvoter: please leave a comment. I'd like to know what's wrong with this answer.